# Child Process exits unexpectedly inside a windows based docker container which spawns through nodejs

Tags: c++, node.js, docker

I am trying to spawn a new process using nodeJs in the following way.

```
public async executeProcess() {

    this._childProcess =  childProcess.spawn ("C:\\app\\SampleApp.exe");
 }
```

Later I am building a docker container based on mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2016 by using the following docker file

```
ARG core=mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2016
ARG target=mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2016

FROM $core as download

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; 
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

ENV NODE_VERSION 10.16.0

RUN Invoke-WebRequest $('https://nodejs.org/dist/v{0}/node-v{0}-win-x64.zip' -f $env:NODE_VERSION) -OutFile 'node.zip' -UseBasicParsing ; \
Expand-Archive node.zip -DestinationPath C:\ ; \
Rename-Item -Path $('C:\node-v{0}-win-x64' -f $env:NODE_VERSION) -NewName 'C:\nodejs'

FROM $target

ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL info

COPY --from=download /nodejs /Bridge

ARG VS_OUT_DIR=.

WORKDIR /
ADD ${VS_OUT_DIR} ./app

WORKDIR /app

SHELL [ "powershell", "-Command"]

RUN Get-ChildItem -Path C:/Bridge -Recurse -Force
RUN Get-ChildItem Env:

SHELL ["cmd", "/C"]

ENTRYPOINT ["c:/nodejs/node.exe", "./lib/app.js"]
```

Comment: What is your question? There is not *nearly enough* information here for anyone to say anything sensibly towards solving your problem. Add more details on what you are trying to accomplish and on how it currently fails. Consider; if *you* were asked this, would you consider the information provided to be adequate?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I just update the description.